# How to concatenate arguments of an array into one string?

Tags: java

This program should use `StringBuilder` to concatenate each word put into the array of strings to form one whole string, separated by spaces. For my output I get nothing because I try and catch exceptions, but it seems to be an ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception. Where is my code flawed?

```
    package practice;

    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Stitching {


    public String stitch(String... words) {

    String wordsAsArray[] = words;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i=0;i<=wordsAsArray.length;i++){

    sb.append(words[i]);
        }

    return sb.toString();


    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    try{

    BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("Please enter a line of words: ");

    String line = br.readLine();

    String wordsAsArray[] = line.trim().split("\\s+");

    Stitching stitching = new Stitching();
    System.out.println("Output: ");
    System.out.println(stitching.stitch(wordsAsArray)); 

} catch(Exception e){}      
    }
}
```

Comment: OH, duh, you catch **all** Exceptions! Why?!?! You can't figure out what's wrong if you silently dispose of your debug info!

Comment: Have you tried debugging this yourself and seeing where program execution diverges from your expectations? And this is a *really* good example of **don't swallow exceptions!**

Comment: @user3580294, correct me if I am wrong, you want space separated words of input from user, then you are splitting it into array `with spaces`, then you are concatenating entire array `without spaces`. That's what you want?

Comment: @Arvind (wrong user :P)

Comment: I have edited this post by making the question more transparent and identifying the exception, for anyone who would like to add their advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `for` loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<=wordsAsArray.length;i++)
```

This will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` Exception because of the `<=` comparison.  Instead use

```
for(int i=0;i<wordsAsArray.length;i++)
```

You aren't seeing a problem when running this code because you're catching the Exception with the `try-catch` block.

When catching an Exception, you should perform some sort of logging; for a quick test a good example is:

```
try {
    // Code here...
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will print the type of exception and code trace that causes it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Your code for `stitch` is very nearly correct.

```
public String stitch(String... words) {
  // String wordsAsArray[] = words;      // <-- redundant
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i=0; i < words.length; i++){  // <-- Less then, not less then equal
    if (i != 0) {
      sb.append(' ');                    // <-- let's add a space between the words.
    }
    sb.append(words[i]);
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Also, you would have seen the problem with the for loop yourself if you hadn't silently ignored your Exception.

```
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace(); // <-- print the Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Caleb said`for(int i=0;i<=wordsAsArray.length;i++)` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Now if you are wondering why `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` well - All array accesses are checked at run time; an attempt to use an index that is less than zero or greater than or equal to the length of the array causes an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown
This should probably fix your code

```
    for(int i=0;i<wordsAsArray.length;i++){

            sb.append(words[i]+" ");
        }
```